# Why solving the inequality $\text{arcsec}(x)>\frac{\pi}{4}$ is giving only half of the answer

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

$$\text{arcsec}(x)>\frac{\pi}{4}$$
Taking $\sec$ on both sides yields
$$\sec(\text{arcsec}(x))>\sec(\frac{\pi}{4})$$
$$x>2^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

But from [this desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z33rqfck2p) one can easily see that this is half of the answer. Why I didn’t get complete answer

Comment: @ViktorGlombik $x$ cannot be $(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @Victorglombik domain = $R-(-1,1)$ . Range = $[0,\pi]-{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Comment: @pRS mHJN 1 This should be written as $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{-1,1\}$ and $[0,\pi]\backslash \{\pi/2\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you have also included $\displaystyle \mathrm{arcsec}(x)=\frac{π}{2}$ in your solution since $\displaystyle \frac{π}{2}>\frac{π}{4}$. But, $\displaystyle \frac{π}{2}$ is not included in the range of $\mathrm{arcsec}$.

So, you have to break the inequality at $\displaystyle \frac{π}{2}$ and the given statement can be written as $$\frac{π}{2}>\mathrm{arcsec} (x) >\frac{π}{4}\cup\\ π\ge \mathrm{arcsec} (x) >\frac{π}{2}\\ \therefore x\in (-\infty,-1]\cup (\sqrt 2,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

The complement of arcsec$(x)>\dfrac\pi4$  is

$$0\le\text{arcsec}(x)\le\dfrac\pi4\iff\sec0\le x\le\sec\dfrac\pi4$$

But $x\ge1$ or $x\le-1$

So, we need $x>\sqrt2$ or $x\le-1$